# ffmpeg : has the quality setting for x265 changed in version 2:6.1-3

Tags: ffmpeg

On Arch Linux, I updated ffmpeg a few days ago from 2:6.1-2 to 2:6.1-3 - now the quality setting on x265 encodes only seems to produce very compressed files. Command used:

```
ffmpeg -probesize 3000M -analyzeduration 3000M -i input.mpg -c:v libx265 -crf 50 -preset veryslow -af "pan=stereo|FL < 1.0*FL + 0.707*FC + 0.707*BL|FR < 1.0*FR + 0.707*FC + 0.707*BR" -c:a libopus -c:s copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:9 output.mkv
```

The input is from a DVD, and the encoded mkv has a bit rate of 116 kb/s - which is very blocky. This has only changed with the update, previously -crf 28 produced about 300 kb/s which was fine.

So what has changed in the latest release of ffmpeg?

Comment: Why are you using `-crf 50` and asking about `-crf 28`?

Comment: crf 50 is the maximum quality setting. I used crf 28 by default, and it gave very small files. So I tried changing to the maximum quality setting, and it made very little difference to the file size and bit rate.

Oh yes looking at the update logs, when thing stopped working libde265 was upgraded to 1.0.15-1 - which is suspicious

Comment: For `crf`, lower value applies higher quality. I suggest you to compare the quality when both versions are set to `-crf 28` (use the same input file).

Comment: This is very strange in you don't give a `crf` value - it seems to encode fine with the default `-crf 28` . But if you set any `crf` it compresses very small and blocky.